# Selenium Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died

Tags: php, selenium, functional-testing, behat

I have a problem with selenium when i try to run my functional tests with behat , my tests worked perfectly before , i only installed php7 instead of php5 I don't know if this is the cause of the problem or not i've also upgraded my ubuntu to 16.04.

this is the error message I get:

[image]

[image]

anyone can help me out with this please ?

Comment: Are you executing in a local network or in a cloud based service?

Comment: I'm executing it in local

Comment: This happens when a certain action is executed or randomly?

Comment: it happens randomly, i just don't know where is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download latest `geckodriver` from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and Looking at the examples at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver)

It seems like you need to do is set marionette to true in the desiered capabilities as below :-

```
$capabilities->setCapability('marionette', true);
```

Example:

```
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub';
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$capabilities->setCapability('marionette', true);
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities, 5000);
```

Comment: i downloaded geckodriver but i don't really know what to do with it or where i should put it ! any explanations please ?

Comment: @zakariabensassi you need to provided that driver path when you are running selenium server jar as :- `java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver = path/to/geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server.jar`..

Comment: thanks for your explanations , i did that it worked , but not perfectly now i can see the browser , but i have another error ! POST /session/ea10aa26-1337-4f3e-842d-cf68f76c24f3/moveto did not match a known command (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: @zakariabensassi have a look [this link](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285) may be it helps..:)

Comment: i still have the issue with the session :/